# XMPP multiplayer gaming: should I store opponents as roster contacts?

Tags: xmpp

I've read all 484 pages of Professional XMPP and read countless forum threads regarding rosters + XMPP and this question is still something I am struggling to solve. I'm looking for insight on best practices, so I at least know which direction to go in.

I'm building a cross-platform (web, iOS & Xbox), turn-based board game. Every player can have up to 100 different matches active at any given moment -- so they could easily skip from one game where it's not there turn to one where it is.

The game will feature a lobby where your list of active games are displayed, along with the name and online status of each opponent for that game (you may have up to 3 opponents, 4 total players per game).

Additionally, each player will have a friends list accessible from a different area which also lists online status.

I am using XMPP behind the scenes, completely transparent to the players, no one will ever sign in with a Jabber client or anything of the sort. I have complete control over how the information is displayed and utilized.

The main aspects I am using XMPP to solve are: notifications when an opponent has made a move, seeing my friends online statuses, and seeing my opponents online statuses, and in-game text chat.

So here's where I start having trouble: obviously your friends list will be contacts in your roster, so you can see their online status. But what about opponents? These are usually random opponents you will only play a single match with and never again -- yet your game with them may last up to 2 weeks.

Keeping in mind that everything is behind the scenes (ex: automatic subscription confirmations, etc) -- would the best course of action be to add each opponent to another group in your roster while the game is in progress and then remove them after the game is complete? That way you get presence notifications when that player is online? Or is this a case where PubSub could be utilized?

I've also considered using multi-user chat so I'd always have access to every users online status without subscriptions, but that seems far from efficient when there could be up to 20k players online at any given moment. Definitely sounds like a battery hog on mobile devices as well.

My other solution is to used share roster lists. Create a roster list for each game and assign that list to each player. Then delete the shared roster list once the game is complete.

Comment: Which XMPP server you are using?

Comment: The latest stable release of ejabberd2 at the moment. Downloaded and installed last night but I'm open to switch to anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would choose Pubsub here. Of course, this means that you have to do some server side work too.

Send a [directed presence](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121#section-4.6) to the opponents. This will allow them to see your presence.

Comment: I have been toying with the idea implementing a server side solution to automatically create a shared roster group for each game, then add all the players into it, and destroy it once the game is completed.

If I go this route, should I just continue to use MUC when the players are in the game? The chat screen sits next to the board, all players of that game can see it, there are no private messages in game.

Comment: I just did a lot of testing with shared rosters and it's too fragile -- at least with eJabberd2. Say players A & B are already subscribed to each other. A, B & C all start a game together, so a roster group is created containing all 3 players. Now both player A & B can get presence notifications of player C. However once the game is completed and I remove the shared roster group, "unavailable" presence notifications are sent for all members of the shared roster -- even if that user is on my global roster. It happens in my application and with iChat.

Comment: I think I spoke too soon in my last comment. Before, I was simply trying to remove my test user from the shared roster group -- that causes the "unavailable" presence notifications. If I actually delete the shared roster group, everyone in the group can still see each other's presence until they sign out. Once they sign in again, the shared group is no longer displayed. Looks like this could be a huge part of the solution.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is the route I'm going with. Creating a shared roster group and putting all the participants in it gives each player presence notifications of their opponents. I can delete the group once the game is finished and the list will be removed from each players roster the next time they sign on.
I'm testing creating pubsub events on the server right now, to subscribe each player to each game. I definitely feel like I'm the right track. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using a multi-user chat for each game, and your own extension to the MUC protocol to handle game-state messages (opponent has made a move). The user can have a roster of their friends at the "global" level, but can still communicate with their opponents (and receive presence) using the MUC level (unless they decide to then add them as a friend).

See also: [Advantages of Pubsub versus MUC](http://metajack.im/2010/01/15/xmpp-pubsub-versus-multiuser-chat/)

Comment: I was definitely thinking about this as a possibility. If I had 100 games going, that would mean I would atomically join the MUC for all 100 of my games upon opening the game. Is that pretty efficient when it comes to XMPP?

I'm most concerned with mobile -- assuming I'll be using a common XMPP lib for Obj-C and you have the iPhone app for the game open, you'll be connected to 100 MUC anytime the game is open. I want to make sure I'm going with an approach that doesn't drain the battery too much and doesn't affect the responsiveness of the device.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using MUCS (instant) would be better in this scenario. If you need to cleanup pubsub nodes of unwanted subscribers, it will definitely be a pain in the ass.